# UWP .appx file naming

Tags: windows, msbuild, uwp, makeappx

I am building an UWP app and I want to have generated package to be named with the build number in order to distinguish the builds.
So far, I have this configuration in the csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Updating AssemblyInfo to Version $(VersionNumber)"></Message>
    <Message Text="Writing to AssemblyInfo files in $(SolutionRoot)"></Message>

    <AssemblyInfo CodeLanguage="CS"
             AssemblyCompany="Company"
             AssemblyProduct="Product"
             AssemblyCopyright="Copyright © Company 2011"
             ComVisible="true"
             AssemblyVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)"
             AssemblyFileVersion="$(BUILD_NUMBER)" />   
  </Target>
```

All good, I can run the msbuild with the `/p:BUILD_NUMBER=1.2.3.4` argument, but this is only reflecting in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.
The .appx file will be named as `MyApplication.Core_1.0.0.0_x86_Test.appx` and not `MyApplication.Core_1.2.3.4_x86_Test.appx`

How can I use the BUILD_NUMBER information to be reflected in the .appx file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number in .appx file name is not set by `AssemblyInfo`. This version number is called [Package version number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering) which is set as a value in the **Version** attribute of the **Package/Identity** element in the app manifest like:

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="e12578ad-9b81-44bb-8651-0b58e44e71b8" Publisher="CN=Jay Zuo" Version="1.2.3.0" />
  ...
</Package>
```

Once you changed the **Version** attribute and then run **MSBuild**, you will get the .appx file named like `MyUWPApp_1.2.3.0_x86.appx`.

Besides this, we usually change the package version number while [creating an app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package). This can be done with Microsoft Visual Studio wizard like following:
[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/images/packaging-screen5.jpg))</sub>